# Spring Array with Strings

Tags: arrays, string, spring, exception

I'm working with some Java that I generate with JAXB but I don't think the JAXB is the problem since the structure of the code generated matches the getter and setter methods for Spring properties that now work but earlier on gave me this same type of exception.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'previousCurrentEstateNo' of bean class [ca.qc.ic.osb.efilingClasses.EIS]: Bean property 'previousCurrentEstateNo' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

The difference here is the use of a String array. I've tried the various suggestions that are supposed to work without success. I'm using Spring 3.0.6.

```
<bean id="eisJointSummary" class="ca.qc.ic.osb.efilingClasses.EIS"    
          scope="prototype" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="previousCurrentEstateNo" >
       <list>
     <value>1234</value>
        </list>
     </property>   
 </bean>
```

within EIS class:

```
 public static class Estate

{

    protected String[] previousCurrentEstateNo;



  public String[] getPreviousCurrentEstateNo() {
        if (this.previousCurrentEstateNo == null) {
            return new String[ 0 ] ;
        }
        String[] retVal = new String[this.previousCurrentEstateNo.length] ;
        System.arraycopy(this.previousCurrentEstateNo, 0, retVal, 0, this.previousCurrentEstateNo.length);
        return (retVal);
    }


    public String getPreviousCurrentEstateNo(int idx) {
        if (this.previousCurrentEstateNo == null) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        return this.previousCurrentEstateNo[idx];
    }

    public int getPreviousCurrentEstateNoLength() {
        if (this.previousCurrentEstateNo == null) {
            return  0;
        }
        return this.previousCurrentEstateNo.length;
    }


    public void setPreviousCurrentEstateNo(String[] values) {
        int len = values.length;
        this.previousCurrentEstateNo = ((String[]) new String[len] );
        for (int i = 0; (i<len); i ++) {
            this.previousCurrentEstateNo[i] = values[i];
        }
    }


    public String setPreviousCurrentEstateNo(int idx, String value) {
        return this.previousCurrentEstateNo[idx] = value;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using a List<> instead?

Comment: also, you're implementing java bean convention, but you're also overloading the setter/getter. Have you tried the code without the overloads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a bean of the type `ca.qc.ic.osb.efilingClasses.EIS` and that class doesn't have a `previousCurrentEstateNo` property.

From what I can tell from the information you provided the `previousCurrentEstateNo` is a property of `Estate`.

I am assuming that `EIS` has a property of type `Estate`?

Try something to this effect:

```
<bean id="eisJointSummary" class="ca.qc.ic.osb.efilingClasses.EIS"    
      scope="prototype" lazy-init="true">

    <property name="nameOfTheEstatePropertyInEIS">
        <bean class="ca.qc.ic.osb.efilingClasses.EIS.Estate">
            <property name="previousCurrentEstateNo">
                <list>
                    <value>1234</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: <bean id="estate2Override" parent="estate2">
           <property name="previousCurrentEstateNo">
                   <list>
                    <value>1234</value>
                   </list>
               </property>
    </bean>
  

  <bean id="eisJointSummaryOverride"          parent="eisJointSummary" >
     <property name="estate" >
       <list>
                <ref bean="estate2Override"/>
              </list>
           </property>   
         
  </bean>